# List executables that are in $PATH without knowing their locations

Tags: python

Is there a way to (glob-like) list executables that match a certain pattern without knowing their actual locations? For example, let's say I have multiple versions of GCC installed: `gcc-10`, `gcc-11` and `gcc-12`, then I need the pattern `gcc-*` to yield something like `['gcc-10', 'gcc-11', 'gcc-12']`.

The behavior I'm after is equivalent to writing `gcc-` and then hitting tab in a Unix shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to iterate over the contents of `PATH`, then iterate over the files in each directory to check if they are executable. (Basically, you need to re-implement the core functionality of the `which` command.) Something like

```
for d in os.environ['PATH'].split(':'):
    for f in pathlib.Path(d).glob('gcc-*'):
        if os.access(f, os.X_OK):
            print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the PATH environment variable, split it, then run a glob search on each extracted directory.

```
import os
from glob import glob
paths = os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.path.pathsep)
glob_pattern = "gcc-*"
found = []
for path in paths:
    found.extend(glob(os.path.join(path, glob_pattern)))
print(found)
```

Comment: This is incorrect if `path` contains `*` or `?`. `os.listdir(path)` + `fnmatch` should be used instead.

Comment: @pts I think its the opposite. `*` and `**` aren't resolved by `os.listdir`. If they are in a PATH component, you'll get an exception. Glob will handle htem. Whether your shell does the same thing when looking through PATH is another question.

Comment: The shell doesn't resolve `?` and `*` in `$PATH`, so Python shouldn't either. Thus I still think my comment is correct.

Comment: @pts - It depends on the shell and its configuration. But you seem to have an edge case where someone puts invalid characters (or any invalid path) in PATH and I guess you want it to fail in that case?

Comment: In fact, libc execlp(3) function is independent of the shell, and it takes `?` and `*` in `$PATH` literally. I think this behavior should be copied, thus `os.listdir(path)` is correct, and `glob.glob(path + ...)` is incorrect in Python.

Comment: If it's the goal to match the current configuration of the user's shell, then Python should run `$SHELL` in a PTY, simulate a few keypresses including a Tab, and see what the shell prints. If this is not the goal, then the behavior should match execlp(3) and the default configuration of the most common shells (Bash, Dash, Zsh, pdksh), thus `os.listdir(path)`.